# Manipulating formal vectors

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, vector

I want to work with a formal vector space spanned by integer triplets:
$$
V=\text{span}\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in\mathbb N^3\},
$$
such that Mathematica can do additions for me. For example,if I input

{1,0,1} + {2,0,1} + 3{1,0,1} - {4,4,7} - 3{2,0,1}

Instead of getting

{-4, -4, -5}

where it is calculated entrywise,

I would like Mathematica to return

4{1,0,1} - 2{2,0,1} - {4,4,7}

What is the simplest way to implement this?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what you want to do with these vectors.  You should not try to force Mma to return what you quote.  But instead of `{1,0,1}` you can use a symbol `a` and later substitute `a -> {1,0,1}`.  Or you can use a special head `4 vec[1,0,1] - 2 vec[2,0,1] ...` and later substitute `vec -> List` as needed.  Or something similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the output you want is to enter the objects representing the vectors as `String` like this:

```
"{1,0,1}" + "{2,0,1}" + 3 "{1,0,1}" - "{4,4,7}" - 3 "{2,0,1}"
```

> `4 {1,0,1} - 2 {2,0,1} - {4,4,7}`

This is just a particularly simple version of what @Szabolcs mentioned in the comment: you don't want the lists representing the vectors to be understood as `List` objects, because otherwise `Times` will always look into them. By giving the "vectors" a `Head` different from `List` for which no special multiplication rules exist, they become like indivisible objects that behave the way you want under multiplication.

The good thing about `String` as the `Head` is that it not only hides the content from `Times`, but also still *displays* the way you want. The latter can in principle also be achieved by coming up with a completely new name like `vec` to wrap your list of components, and then defining how that new object displays by using `Format`:

```
Format[vec[x_, y_, z_]] = {x, y, z}
vec[1, 0, 1] + vec[2, 0, 1] + 3 vec[1, 0, 1] - vec[4, 4, 7] - 3 vec[2, 0, 1]
```

> `4 {1,0,1} -2 {2,0,1} - {4,4,7}`

With the latter approach, you can also add more tricks:

```
vec[x_, y_, z_] /; GCD[x, y, z] != 1 := 
 Module[{g = GCD[x, y, z]}, g Apply[vec, {x, y, z}/g]]

vec[2, 2, 4]

(* ==> 2 {1, 1, 2} *)
```

This way, the integers in the `vec` components are reduced to the point where they are mutually prime, further reducing the number of vectors in a general expression, which is a simplification that can be done without doing all the other multiplications.

Comment: Both of these work thanks. But how can I also implement bracket / distributive rule, i.e. how can I make Mathematica return "4{1,0,1}+2{1,1,1}" when I type "2(2"{1,0,1}"+"{1,1,1}")", or "2(2vec[1,0,1]+vec[1,1,1])" if I use Format?

Comment: @JeffBaxter: that last bit is the job of `Expand` ; remark that you can also use `MatrixForm` as a wrapper around your vectors.